# Live reverb effect to all audio

Tags: linux, audio

Is it possible to apply live reverb or hall effect to all media that is played?

I know how to apply an effect to a single file but I want to add a reverb effect at a low-level that this is applied to all audio played on linux (browser, file, ...).

Comment: posting as comment since not at my computer. Simple answer is "yes" with jackd and using its patching to use a verb plugin. But jackd eco-system has many possible apps that are jackd compatible and using with pulseaudio brings its own set of challenges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply have to install [PulseEffects](https://github.com/wwmm/pulseeffects)